# After dual booting from Ubuntu to Windows nVidia GPU disappears?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, windows-8, reboot

I use Grub to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. When I first boot into Ubuntu, reboot, then select Windows 8.1 from Grub and try to play a game it complains there is no the nVidia GPU.

In Ubuntu 16.04 I have nVidia GE Force GT650M (laptop) GPU turned off due to bugs I've been working on for 3 years (starting with Ubuntu 14.04). But in Windows 8.1 I have nVidia GPU turned on albeit with Optimus to only have it active on an application by application basis.

If I'm always rebooting with Windows 8.1 the nVidia GPU never seems to disappear.

**Why does nVidia GPU disappear after running Ubuntu and then rebooting and selecting Windows?**

Answer (score 3):

When you boot Ubuntu it powers off the nVidia GPU. When you reboot power remains off so Windows doesn't see it. The same thing can happen with other devices when you reboot from Windows back to Grub and then Ubuntu.

The solution is to **Shut Down** and then **Power On**.

There is a reason why they call it "warm boot" versus "cold boot" and "soft boot" versus "hard boot". This is just one example.